# Effective methods for DBpedia queries

Tags: dbpedia

I've been trying to implement a query to find the birth date of a given person using DBPedia.  This seems easy enough but I'm finding a lot of different tags to match names and birth dates, not all of which show up under all entities.
For instances we have `dbp:name`, `dbp:birthName`, `foaf:givenName`, `foaf:surname`, `dbo:birthDate`, `dbo:birthYear`, `dbp:dateOfBirth`, etc.

I'm wondering if...

1 - Is there a higher level library I can use (preferably in python but Java is ok too) that "understands" these different tags and that can help form appropriate queries to search and combine the different information.

2 - Is there any guidance on how to accomplish this. For instance, is it better to use the ontology (`dbo`) or the property (`dbp`) or the `foaf`.  I'm also curious if a common approach is to pre-download all the possible tags and search on all that seem applicable and then select the "best" returned data. If someone could offer some guidance or point me to a good tutorial, I'd appreciate it.  I've found some info on the web but nothing that really addresses my question.

Comment: Welcome to crowd-sourced data... DBpedia is basically an RDFization of Wikipedia, and both are moving targets. Cleaning up the data in Wikipedia, and improving the extractors/RDFizers of DBpedia, are the main things you can do to help yourself and others. Also note that the questions you're asking are frowned on here, as there is no "correct" answer, but lots of opinion.